# The convergence of this integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x+x^{2}\sin^{2}(\pi x)}~dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The elementary question is below :

**Q :** Is this integral convergent $?$
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x+x^{2}\sin^{2}(\pi x)}~dx
\end{align}

But it seems to be not easy to deduce that this integral converges or not. I think the key point is that sin function is in the denominator. Are there any suggestions of this problem ? I will be appreciated.

Comment: Not a solution but an idea: One could try and split the domain of integration into the set $A:=\{x^2\sin^2(\pi x) >x^\frac{3}{2}\}$ and its complement. On $A$ the integral should converge as it is. On its complement it could be possible to show that $\frac{1}{x}$ converges due to the 'shrinking' thickness of $A^c$ and hence is a dominating function for the integral on $A^c$. Anyhow, this would be a pretty rough way of showing the statement.

Comment: According to Mathematica, the integral converges to $\approx1.44409$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The convergence of

$$I = \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x+x^{2}\sin^{2}(\pi x)}\ dx$$ is equivalent to the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ where

$$I_n = \int_{n-1/2}^{n+1/2}\frac{1}{x+x^{2}\sin^{2}(\pi x)}\ dx.$$

Following inequalities / equalities hold for $n \in \mathbb N$:

$$\begin{aligned}
0 \le I_n &=  \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{1}{(y+n)+(y+n)^{2}\sin^{2}(\pi x)}\ dy\\
&\le \frac{1}{n-1/2}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{1}{1+(n-1/2)\sin^{2}(\pi y)}\ dy\\
&=\frac{2}{n-1/2}\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{1}{1+(n-1/2)\sin^{2}(\pi y)}\ dy\\
&\le \frac{2}{n-1/2}\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{1}{1+4(n-1/2)z^2}\ dz\\
&\le \frac{2}{n-1/2}\int_{0}^\infty\frac{1}{1+4(n-1/2)z^2}\ dz\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2(n-1/2)^{3/2}}
\end{aligned}$$

as:

- $x \mapsto \frac{1}{1+(n-1/2)\sin^{2}(\pi x)}$ is an even function.
- $\sin (\pi x) \ge 2x$ on the interval $[0, 1/2]$. This is a convexity inequality.
- $\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{1+b^2t^2} = \frac{\pi}{2b}$ for $b \gt 0$.

**Therefore $I$ converges as $\sum I_n$ converges.**